# Too little data in the starting month causes the text on the x-axis to overlap

Tags: charts

When the data is displayed in the month dimension, when there are only a few days left in the starting month, the date text of the next month will overlap with the starting month, The current solution for me is to increase the judgment rule: the total proportion of monthly data * the total length of the time axis will not be displayed if it is less than the width of the date text.
Is there any better solution? or a better design

[image]

Comment: Can you rephrase the question so that it isn't about the technical solution but about improving the user experience? Otherwise the question isn't suitable for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least three solutions for this:

1. The whole axis doesn't have to start with the start of the filtering date. You could start the axis with the start of selected month, but not display the data for the data that wasn't asked for - that way the labels would align properly;
2. In the case where the labels overlap, you could choose to hide one of the labels, it should be ok in your case if "2023-04" would be hidden, as "2023-05" provides enough context.
3. In the case where the labels overlap, you could choose to align one of the labels a little lower than the other one - that way both labels would be displayed.

P.S. You should probably consider showing "stabs" on the axis, or vertical lines for where the months actually start. Otherwise it can be confusing, especially with the overlapping labels.

Comment: We ended up using the second option, the first one is also good, it is easier to implement